# How to do auto-selection to mask data using c++

Tags: c++, class, struct, selection, auto

I have some issues regarding c++. I need to do an auto-selection for masking a bundle of data. As for now, I only have a hard-coded code (pre-defined) where the user needs to change the code to mask the columns if there is anything other than the stated event. I did not know how to make the code to do auto-select for the masking. I think it needs to apply a rule-based and some sort of class or struct. But I did not know where to apply it. Below is my code to mask the data. Thank you in advance..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

//code to read the CSV file
vector<vector<string>> read_csv(string filename){
    ifstream input_file(filename);
    vector<string> row_items;
    vector<vector<string>> result;

    if (!input_file.is_open()) throw runtime_error("Could not open the file");

    string line, item;

    while(getline(input_file, line)){
        row_items.clear();
        stringstream ss(line);
        while(getline(ss, item, ',')){
            row_items.push_back(item);
        }
        result.push_back(row_items);
    }
    input_file.close();
    return result;
}

//code to write and save CSV file
void write_csv(string filename, vector<vector<string>> dataset){
    ofstream output_file(filename);
    for (int rows = 0; rows < dataset.size(); rows++){
        for(int cols = 0; cols < dataset[rows].size(); cols++){
            output_file << dataset[rows][cols];
            if (cols != dataset[rows].size() - 1) output_file << ",";
        }
        output_file << "\n";
    }
    output_file.close();
    cout<<"\nYour File Already Saved as CSV!\n";
}

//code to do the masking
//replace the character or integer into 'x'
string  mask_string(string str_value){
    string new_str = str_value.substr(0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < str_value.length(); i++){
        if (isspace(str_value.at(i))) new_str += ' ';
        else if (str_value.at(i) == '.') new_str += '.';
        else new_str += 'x';
    }
    return new_str;
}

//masking based on event
void mask_column(vector<vector<string>> &dataset, int event)
{
    if (event == 1) //energy consumption event
    {
        for (int rows = 1; rows < dataset.size(); rows++)
        {
            for(int cols = 0; cols < dataset[rows].size(); cols++)
            {
                if(cols != 0 && cols != 6 && cols != 7 && cols != 8 && cols != 10 && cols != 13 && cols != 14 && cols != 15 && cols != 17 && cols!= 22)   //revealed columns
                {
                    if (cols == 1) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                        else if (cols == 3) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                            else if (cols == 9) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                                else if (cols == 12) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                                    else if (cols == 16) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                                        else dataset[rows][cols] = mask_string(dataset[rows][cols]); //fully masking columns
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (event == 2) //non-technical loss event
    {
        for (int rows = 1; rows < dataset.size(); rows++)
        {
            for(int cols = 0; cols < dataset[rows].size(); cols++)
            {
                if(cols != 0 && cols != 6 && cols != 7 && cols != 8 && cols != 10 && cols != 13 && cols != 14 && cols != 15 && cols!= 18 && cols!= 19 && cols!= 20 && cols!= 21) //revealed columns
                {
                    if (cols == 1) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                        else if (cols == 3) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                            else if (cols == 9) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                                else if (cols == 12) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                                    else if (cols == 16) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                                        else dataset[rows][cols] = mask_string(dataset[rows][cols]); //fully masking columns
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (event == 3) //electricity usage pattern
    {
        for (int rows = 1; rows < dataset.size(); rows++)
        {
            for(int cols = 0; cols < dataset[rows].size(); cols++)
            {
                if(cols != 0 && cols != 6 && cols != 7 && cols != 8 && cols != 10 && cols!= 13 && cols != 14 && cols != 15 && cols != 17 && cols != 22) //revealed columns
                {
                    if (cols == 1) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                        else if (cols == 3) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                            else if (cols == 9) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                                else if (cols == 12) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                                    else if (cols == 16) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                                        else dataset[rows][cols] = mask_string(dataset[rows][cols]); //fully masking columns
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (event == 4) //masking all PII data
    {
        for (int rows = 1; rows < dataset.size(); rows++)
        {
            for(int cols = 0; cols < dataset[rows].size(); cols++)
            {
                if(cols != 0 && cols != 6 && cols!= 7 && cols != 8 && cols!= 10 && cols!= 13 && cols!= 14 && cols!= 15 && cols != 17 && cols!= 18 && cols!= 19 && cols!= 20 && cols != 21 && cols != 22) //revealed columns
                {
                    if (cols == 1) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                        else if (cols == 3) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                            else if (cols == 9) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                                else if (cols == 12) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                                    else if (cols == 16) dataset[rows][cols] = dataset[rows][cols].replace(4, dataset[rows][cols].length(), mask_string(dataset[rows][cols].substr(4))); //partially masking columns
                                        else dataset[rows][cols] = mask_string(dataset[rows][cols]); //fully masking columns
                }`enter code here`
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    //shows current date and time
    time_t now = time(0);
    char* date_time = ctime(&now);

    cout << "Current Date and Time:  " << date_time;

    cout << "\nWELCOME TO IDSA PROGRAM\n";
    cout << "~We Are Protecting Customer Data~\n";

    //read CSV file
    int event;
    vector<vector<string>> dataset = read_csv("originaldataset.csv");

    //User choose event
    cout << "\nYou May Choose The Available Events:\n\n";
    cout << "1. Energy Consumption\n";
    cout << "2. Non-Technical Loss\n";
    cout << "3. Electricity Usage Pattern\n";
    cout << "4. Masking all  PII Data";
    cout << "\n\nPlease Enter The Event: ";
    cin >> event;

    mask_column(dataset, event);
    write_csv("masked_originaldataset.csv", dataset);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by "auto-select for the masking". It's also not clear what "masking" is.

Comment: off-topic: your choice of formatting the code is ... well let's say not recommended. Having long lines is pretty counter-productive because you want to avoid horizontal scrolling when reading the code. Usually there is an 80 or 100 or rarely an 120 max column width. Another thing avoid if statements on the same line.

Comment: off-topic: you have a lot of repeating code. You should identify the parts of the code that repeat and make them into functions.

Comment: off topic: `if (cols != 0 && cols != 6 && cols != 7 && cols != 8 && ...` you can make this more readable by creating a function: `if (!is_one_of(cols, {0, 6, 7, 8, ....}))`. If all `if`s are the same you can go one step further and do `if (is_revealed_column(cols))`.

Comment: To automatically mask certain data (like credit card numbers or whatever) you need to know how to identify the data you want masked.  You mention using a "rule-based" system.  How would you specify the rules?  Row, column, and list of match regex/replace regex would work - that would allow you to say: if the format of x column matches y then replace these specific bits and if it matches z then replace these other bits instead.

Comment: @bolov im so sorry, but how to make it as a function so that i did not need to repeat for every event.. im stuck doing the function, thats why i do the repeating in every event

Comment: @JerryJeremiah i specify the rules based on event choose by the user. for example in customer billing data, user want to see energy consumption in certain area. so the program should only reveal consumption and postcode. other fields either full or partial mask. for PII data, apply full mask. others apply partial mask.

Comment: @star that is already what the program does. I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: If you don't really need a rules-based system but are just looking for a way to make the function more concise with less duplication and easier to configure what about something like https://onlinegdb.com/pYVCQyzMb

Comment: use postgres to store it. you hide nothing this way

Comment: @bolov im sorry if you didn't understand.. i tried implement your function, but my output didn't appear as what it should appear.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah thank you for the given code. i need to use a rules-based system as the user can create a new event even though there are 4 pre-defined events in the code. if let says i want to store certain columns that contain PII data to be in one group, can these columns store in struct or class? how to do the struct or class, so that didn't need to write for every events.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин did you mean to store the data? how suppose it needs to be done after you says i hide nothing from what i do.

Comment: i see `.csv` . you can either use say openssl for encryption of this file or postgres to store this in encrypted base. their lib for c++ isn't bad

Comment: https://github.com/alexeyneu/BlockZero/blob/65b98a062bc5649c7b3cb1198d6cdbe4f5a597a8/connection/x.cpp#L234-L239

Comment: @star So the map holds four things currently but you don't need to hard code the initializer - you could read the data from a file instead.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah meaning that, if i create new event, i still can use the initializer. thus, no need to use struct or class. it is like that?